# How to create an Entity Framework model from an existing SQLite database in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, sqlite

I've installed the `System.Data.SQLite` ADO.NET Provider from http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/. I can connect to the database from within Visual Studio, I can open table schemas, views etc.

I'd like to use an existing SQLite database to create an Entity Framework model in Visual Studio 2008.

When I try to create a new ADO.NET Entity Data Model (.edmx) file using the wizard,  the existing SQLite connection is not in the list though. Also, it's not possible to create a SQLite connection because there is no provider for SQLite. It only lists SQL Server, SQL Server file and SQL Server Compact 3.5.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

**UPDATE:**

*It worked after having uninstalled and re-installed the SQLite ADO.NET Data Provider (SQLite-1.0.65.0-setup.exe).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQLite provider should be available in VS... you can run the "Design-Time Configuration" tool from the SQLite.NET menu (in Windows Start menu) to register the provider with VS.

Note that if you're using an Express version of VS, you can't add third-party ADO.NET providers...

Comment: I already did that. I have the SQLite components in the Toolbox, I also can edit table schemas and data in VS, but the EF wizard doesn't show a SQLite provider for a new DB connection.

Comment: Which version of VS are you using ?

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 - see tag and title ;-)

Comment: Yes, but you didn't specify if it was an Express edition. Anyway, I don't know why it doesn't work for you. I used Entity Framework with SQLite before, and it worked fine for me

Comment: Thanks for your answer anyway. Tomorrow I'll it on another machine.

Comment: D'oh! Worked on a second machine. And, it worked on my machine after having uninstalled and re-installed the SQLite ADO.NET Data Provider. Thanks again!