# F# Type Provider for SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, f#, type-providers, f#-3.0

I have searched for the last month or so to no avail. Fsharpx, F# powerpack, codeplex, github, fssnip.net, hubfs.net, System.Data.SQLite, dba.stackexchange.com, F# & SQLite forums, blogs, etc. all turn up empty. As of today an F# Type Provider for SQLite does not exist in the public domain. Can you prove me wrong?

Assuming no body can prove me wrong my next step is to go about creating an F# Type Provider for SQLite which I am not very confident in my ability to do so (I'll get it done but it won't be pretty and it will take me a lot more effort that someone familiar with F#) but it will force me to learn how. I'm a student of F# and not a professional yet. I also have never created something in and for the Public Domain. Should I attempt that at GitHub? Or is that overkill and the solution is going to be simple enough to post the various answers/solutions of code here in this thread (and the final, final elegant solution(s) at fssnip.net)?

P.S. - I hope this post is of interest to GlennFerrieLive because he made a post [Project ideas for FSharp Type Providers? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869983/project-ideas-for-fsharp-type-providers)

BTW - A HUGE thanks to all the incredibly helpful people on this site and others and F# is awesome, thanks Don Syme!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to let you know, [my SQL type provider](https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider) now supports SQLite, feel free to contribute and help testing, it is not production ready.

Answer (score 5):

Entity Framework supports sqlite, so you should be able to create an `.edmx` file for your database schema then use the [EDMX type provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361038.aspx) to generate your types.

You may be able to create your `.edmx` file using the design-time support available in Visual Studio through the [System.Data.SQLite plugin](http://system.data.sqlite.org/) -- see this earlier SO post: [How to create an Entity Framework model from an existing SQLite database in Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514785/how-to-create-an-entity-framework-model-from-an-existing-sqlite-database-in-visu)

Finally, CodeProject has a nice article on using SQLite from within Visual Studio; it's not related to F# but might be useful for general background info: [Using SQLite Embedded Database with Entity Framework and Linq-to-SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/236918/Using-SQLite-embedded-database-with-entity-framewo).

Comment: Entity Framework (EF):  1. I wasn't aware that you could make the EdmxFile work with SQLite even though that results in using EF, so that is great to learn, thanks.

Comment: Entity Framework (EF) cont'd:  2. My understanding of EF (I have not used EF) is that its use/benefit is to abstract away the relational schema. You just work with the fields in the db with no regard to tables/views. Therefore you cannot be concerned about maximizing the performance of your queries because you have no idea how EF is building the needed queries in the background for you (i.e. table joins for example). So the tradeoff of using EF is, no concern for query performance, something I would ideally like to avoid by avoiding the use of EF.

Comment: Entity Framework (EF) cont'd:  3. That being said, you have still provided a F# Type Provider solution for SQLite when currently I have found none and I thank you for that!

Comment: Entity Framework (EF) Type Providers for SQLite: [EdmxFile Type Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362313.aspx) vs. [SqlEntityConnection Type Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362322.aspx)?    
===

What about using SqlEntityConnection Type Provider as another EF option for SQLite or does that get back to the same problem where it only works with MS SQL products? Unlike SqlDataConnection the SqlEntityConnection has a Provider parameter (i.e. I can use System.Data.SQLite.dll).

Comment: Confusion created by the name [SqlDataConnection Type Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362320.aspx): This should have been called "MS SQL" (MsSqlDataConnection) instead and not just "SQL". "SQL" makes you think it will work with a variety of SQL databases when in fact it only works with Microsoft SQL products. There is no Provider parameter to allow you to connect to non-MS SQL products.

**The solution I want for SQLite would be the same as the "SqlDataConnection Type Provider"** instead of using the "EdmxFile Type Provider" or the "SqlEntityConnection Type Provider".

Comment: WARNING - Learning-in-Progress: I may have some of my understanding in my comments above incorrect.   

Now I'm off to get Jack P.'s EdmxFile Type Provider solution working with SQLite. I'll post back on that...   

P.S. - Is there a better way to post beyond the comment limit of 600 characters per comment so that you don't have to break it up across several comment posts?

Comment: @Rick - the 600 character limit was put in place to discourage long rambling discussions on what is intended to be a Q&A site, not a discussion board. Trying to bypass this limit is not an appropriate response. Your understanding of EF is incorrect. EF does not abstract away the existence of tables or joins, and while it does build SQL based on your LINQ statement, it is no worse at that than other ORM's. If you're going to hand-craft your SQL, what do you need any ORM for (type provider or not)?